# Why jquery-jcrop is destroying my Leaflet map when I use the destroy() function?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, jcrop

I've created a very simple functional example with `jcrop` that creates a square on an image:

```js
$('#container').Jcrop({
    onSelect: function(c){
        alert(JSON.stringify(c));
        this.destroy()
    }
})
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/css/jquery.Jcrop.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>

<img src="https://d3o1694hluedf9.cloudfront.net/market-750.jpg" id="container">
```

In this example, the function `this.destroy()` works as I expect, it destroys the shadow layer that `jcrop` creates on my image. So far, everything is fine. However, when I try to do the same thing with leaflet, it doesn't work at all. Here is what I've tried:

```js
var mymap = L.map('container', {
    center:[-23.553670644165493, -46.648217439651496],
    zoom:18,
    maxZoom:19,
    zoomControl:false,
    attributionControl:false
});         
var lyrOSRHOT = L.tileLayer.provider('OpenStreetMap.HOT');
mymap.addLayer(lyrOSRHOT);

$('#container').Jcrop({
    onSelect: function(c){
        alert(JSON.stringify(c));
        this.destroy()
    }   
})
```

```css
#container{
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<!-- Leaflet -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet-src.min.js" integrity="sha512-XQr+/1RXvYozXiwrumwtu3lqQmVwZ8nkLUrC/mc3HBHw4Imh++RXjwtLQFuOz3i65j9CSfKt50x6w/uUY2ovOQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-providers/1.12.0/leaflet-providers.min.js" integrity="sha512-LixflAm9c0/qONbz9F1Ept+QJ6QBpb7wUlPuyv1EHloTVgwSK8j3yMV3elnElGQcv7Y5QTFlF/FqyeE/N4LnKQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<!-- jQUERY JCROP-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/css/jquery.Jcrop.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height:100vh; width: 100vw"></div>
```

I followed the same logic from my first sample, but after selecting a part of the map, the function `destroy()` is also destroying the `Leaflet` map (that doesn't happen when it's an image). Does anyone know what could be happening? Could it be a conflict that `jcrop` has with `Leaflet` and what I'm trying to do will not be possible without modifying the libraries?

Comment: [Known issue](https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/issues/34)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving it with a workaround that creates a different `div` element that uses the same space that the Leaflet map is using... The solution is the following:

```js
var mymap = L.map('container', {
    center:[-23.553670644165493, -46.648217439651496],
    zoom:18,
    maxZoom:19,
    zoomControl:false,
    attributionControl:false,
    renderer: L.canvas()
});         
var lyrOSRHOT = L.tileLayer.provider('OpenStreetMap.HOT');
mymap.addLayer(lyrOSRHOT);

const id = "aux-container"
createFakeMap(id)
$('#'+id).Jcrop({
    onSelect: function(c){
        alert(JSON.stringify(c));
        this.destroy()
    }   
}) 

// auxiliary function
function createFakeMap(id){
    const div = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.setAttribute("id", id);
    div.style.height = '100vh';
    div.style.width = '100vw';
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<!-- Leaflet -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet-src.min.js" integrity="sha512-XQr+/1RXvYozXiwrumwtu3lqQmVwZ8nkLUrC/mc3HBHw4Imh++RXjwtLQFuOz3i65j9CSfKt50x6w/uUY2ovOQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-providers/1.12.0/leaflet-providers.min.js" integrity="sha512-LixflAm9c0/qONbz9F1Ept+QJ6QBpb7wUlPuyv1EHloTVgwSK8j3yMV3elnElGQcv7Y5QTFlF/FqyeE/N4LnKQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<!-- jQUERY JCROP-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/css/jquery.Jcrop.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height:100vh; width: 100vw; position: absolute; z-index:1"></div>
```

I've created the div element using Javascript instead of HTML because the `destroy` function is going to destroy this element all the times that I execute it. With Javascript, I can create it again dynamically when I need it, while not destroying my map and its state.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're attaching Jcrop and Leaflet to the same `#container` element. It looks like calling Jcrop.destroy() is removing everything associated with that element.

Can you use two separate elements for these two libraries? Maybe attach Leaflet to a wrapper or parent element of the one that you're using to call Jcrop.

Here's my version on using two separate elements for the map and the Jcrop component.

```html
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!-- Leaflet -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet-src.min.js" integrity="sha512-XQr+/1RXvYozXiwrumwtu3lqQmVwZ8nkLUrC/mc3HBHw4Imh++RXjwtLQFuOz3i65j9CSfKt50x6w/uUY2ovOQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-providers/1.12.0/leaflet-providers.min.js" integrity="sha512-LixflAm9c0/qONbz9F1Ept+QJ6QBpb7wUlPuyv1EHloTVgwSK8j3yMV3elnElGQcv7Y5QTFlF/FqyeE/N4LnKQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <!-- jQUERY JCROP-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/css/jquery.Jcrop.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.15/js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper {
            position: relative;
            height:100vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }

        #cropper {
            height:100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #map {
            height:100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .jcrop-holder {
            z-index: 600;
            background: transparent !important;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="cropper"></div>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var mymap = L.map('map', {
            center:[-23.553670644165493, -46.648217439651496],
            zoom:18,
            maxZoom:19,
            zoomControl:false,
            attributionControl:false
        });
        var lyrOSRHOT = L.tileLayer.provider('OpenStreetMap.HOT');
        mymap.addLayer(lyrOSRHOT);

        $('#cropper').Jcrop({
            onSelect: function(c){
                console.log(c);
                console.log(c.x);
                console.log(c.y);
                console.log(c.w);
                console.log(c.h);
                this.destroy();
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When I attach different ids for them, `jcrop` doesn't allow me to create the square that I need. It only creates the square on the element id that I give to it on `$('#id').Jcrop`... However, on my first sample, the img tag also has the id `container` and it doesn't make the `destroy` function to destroy the background image... I don't know why, but the behavior on these two examples are different...

Comment: Because the JCrop destroy function doesn't remove the element from the browser, it removes the JavaScript functionality that you've attached to that element. Since you attach Leaflet before Jcrop, you lose all Leaflet functionality after you destroy it. You could try re-attaching Leaflet after you destroy the Jcrop element, or just not run the destroy function at all.

Comment: I've tried both of them already... But if I try to re-attach Leaflet after I destroy the Jcrop element I receive an error. Apparently, the destroy function is destroying the entire HTML element that is necessary to make Leaflet work... About not using the destroy function, my goal is to make the shadow layer created by jcrop disappear... I'm not sure how I could achieve this same goal with other means by now.

Comment: Try setting the `bgOpacity` setting of jCrop to: 0 and remove the destroy() function onSelect

Comment: Even though `bgOpacity` makes it transparent, that solution wouldn't work for me because the idea is to use the Leaflet map after destroying the `Jcrop` layer... I can't do that while Jcrop has this layer above Leaflet...

Comment: @raylight - updated my answer to include a version that uses separate elements for each library.